# Find the mean and variance of a random variable composed of random variables.

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be random variables all with unknown distributions, whose mean is 0, their deviation is 1 and all are independent from one another. Let $Y=\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}$. Find $E[Y]$ and $\sigma(Y)$.

This problem may look easy, but I got stuck in how to approach it. What I thought is that if the mean of all the $X_i$'s is $0$, then the mean of $Y$ should also be 0. But I'm still pretty confused. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your intuition about the mean is correct. Remember that expectation is linear, i.e. $E(aX+bY)=aEX+bEY$. Standard deviation is based on variance, which is not linear but obeys a similar rule (which you can derive from the definition of the variance as a certain expected value).

Comment: @Karl Thanks a lot for the help, so it was mainly a problem of using the linear property of expectation in order to find the expected value and the variance. Will try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y can also be written $\frac {\sum X} n$.

The expectation of Y is $E(\frac {\sum X} n)=\frac 1 nE(\sum X)=\frac 1 n \sum E(X)=\frac 1 n0=0$, in accordance with your intuition.

The variance of Y is $var(Y)=var(\frac {\sum X} n)=\frac 1 {n^2}var(\sum X)=\frac 1 {n^2}\sum var(X)=\frac n {n^2}=\frac 1 n$. Standard deviation is the square root of this, $\sigma(Y)=\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$.

You can only do this if the variables are iid, which they are.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have one question, I don't understand the step you make from $\frac{1}{n^2}var(\sum X)$ to $\frac{1}{n^2}\sum var(X)=\frac{1}{n^2}$. How can that step happen if the variance isn't exactly linear because of properties like $Var(X+Y) = Var(X)+Var(Y)+2cov(X,Y)$. Is it because of the iid, and why does it result in 1?

Comment: You’re right! Each individual variance is 1 (with covariance terms being 0) so they add up to n. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused because of that. So the variance should go as $Var(Y)=\frac{1}{n}$ and the deviation as $\sigma(Y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, right?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. fixed in the answer

Comment: Alright, thanks for the contribution!